# Nexus 5 Dropbox Photo Duplication

Tags: nexus-5, dropbox

The Camera Uploads folder is filling up with duplicates with -1, -2 etc. appended on the end of each file. I can't understand why it doesn't detect they are the same, I assume something is changing the metadata slightly. Does anyone have experience with this issue?

Comment: Just checked and I'm not seeing this happening with the Camera Uploads from my Nexus 5. Do you have any other software installed on yours that does anything with pictures, any photo editing software, any photo sharing software, any alternate gallery/viewing software?

Comment: Not that I am aware of. I'm new to Android but other than the default apps and Dropbox I don't think so. Also I have Auto Backup turned off.